# AUTO_INCREMENT for a table with engine type InnoDB getting reset without server restart?

Tags: mysql, server, innodb, auto-increment, restart

I am setting auto increment value to 10 in test table of mysql and where engine type is InnoDB. while I am not inserting any entry in the table, it is getting set to 1 after 12 hours without any server restart. Ideally auto increment counter is set to zero after server restart but that is not being done. I am not able to figure out why ?

Comment: How do you know it change from 10 to 1?

Comment: Hi, I read on stackoverflow and also tried inserting a row in table , my conclusions are based on that insert only .

Comment: It seems strange. Can you recreate it with some sort of statements?

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t1`;
CREATE TABLE `t1` (  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `masterform_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=194953 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;                       ------- This AUTO_INCREMENT is reset to 1 without any DB server restart after 12 hours(this was the time when I checked) , the auto_increment column was reset to 1 and show create table was also not showing AUTO_INCREMENT=194953  at that time , which it was showing initially .

Comment: If no "ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1" is executed. Too strange. No idea.

Comment: Please provide `SELECT MAX(id) FROM ...` before the 12 hours is up.

Comment: Did you `DELETE` any rows?